# Rolling Dice or Cumulative Binomial Distribution with a Twist

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am making a game where players can win or lose based on dice they throw.

- Player throws $M$ number of dice.
- By default a success is considered when a die rolls $5$ or $6$.
- Player needs to get $N$ successful dice to win.

The basic formula to calculate the probability of the player winning looks like this (Cumulative Binomial Distribution):

$$1 - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \binom{M}{k}  p^k (1-p)^{M-k} $$

Then $p = 2 / 6$ (probability of success where $5$ & $6$ are considered as success)

The player can also have different effects during the game that increase their chances:

- Blessed - Dice sides that count as success: $4 ,5 ,6$
- Cursed - Dice sides that count as success: $6$

In these cases I just change the $p$ to $3 / 6$ in case of Blessed and to $1 / 6$ in cased of Cursed.

Now I have the problem calculating the probability in the following case:

> "Each $6$ your roll counts as $2$ successes" - I guess this is self explanatory. So now each dice that rolls a $6$ will be considered as $2$ successes.

How can I adapt my formula to take this effect into consideration?

Let me know if something is not clear.

---

Edit: By default when you throw a die you can get the following results:

$$\matrix{1 &\text{fail}\\
2 &\text{fail}\\
3 &\text{fail}\\
4 &\text{fail}\\
5 &\text{success}\\
6 &\text{success}}$$

When player is Blessed it changes to:
$$\matrix{1 &\text{fail}\\
2 &\text{fail}\\
3 &\text{fail}\\
4 &\text{success}\\
5 &\text{success}\\
6 &\text{success}}$$

When player is Cursed, you get:
$$\matrix{1 &\text{fail}\\
2 &\text{fail}\\
3 &\text{fail}\\
4 &\text{fail}\\
5 &\text{fail}\\
6 &\text{success}}$$

---

Edit2: Let's forget about dice for a second. Seems like I won't be able to reuse the old formula.

Let's say that each turn for $M$ turns, I get a value with the following probability:

$$\matrix{Value &Normal&Blessed&Cursed\\
0 &4/6 & 3/6 & 5/6\\
1 &1/6 & 2/6 & 0/6\\
2 &1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6\\
}$$

How do I calculate the probability that the sum of the values is at least $N$ or bigger?

Comment: No longer binomial, so I don't see a simple, straightforward 'adaptation', except for the Cursed case. In the other cases you have three outcomes on each roll: 'Failure:' face too small, 'Success:' big but not 6, and 'Super-success:' 6. Super-success counts double. Simulation easy for given values of M and N.

Comment: I dont understand the mechanic on cursed or blessed... can you explain better please? And try to use mathjax, the text is hard to understand or read.

Comment: Added the explanation regarding Blessed and Cursed in the main post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help with the editing!

Comment: @Revolter no problem. The unique big change that I did is just write the binomial coefficient in it standard notation instead of using factorials, that is $$\binom{M}{k}:=\frac{M!}{k!(M-k)!}$$

Comment: If you want to know how to edit something using mathjax take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Searching in the linked web, by example by "table", you can found different ways to write tables, etc...

Comment: @Masacroso that's helpful, I'll use it next time I need to post something here. Thanx again ;)

Comment: Take a look at [this site](http://anydice.com/), if you read the documentation (by example related to arbitrary dice) you can see very fast any probability distribution that you want. And probably using the conditional blocks you can force that a throw with negative values have value zero. I updated the image of the charts (and the notebook also).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different way to do (maybe easier, computationally speaking) is just using a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of the kind

$$g(x)=(q+p_1x+p_2x^2)^M\tag{1}$$

that represents the act of throwing $M$ dice, where sides of dice with probability $q$ add zero points, sides of dice with probability $p_1$ add one point and sides of dice with probability $p_2$ add two points.

When we expand $g$ we have that each monomial $c_kx^k$ represent the probability $c_k$ to have $k$ successes in the throw. Hence using the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) (with [multi-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)) we have that

$$g(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|=M}\binom{M}{\alpha}q^{\alpha_1}(p_1x)^{\alpha_2}(p_2x^2)^{\alpha_3},\quad \alpha\in\Bbb N^3_{\ge 0}\tag{2}$$

Using a program we can easily choose the coefficients that we are interested on. By example using the Wolfram language we can use the code

```
g[x_, p1_, p2_, M_] := ((1 - p1 - p2) + p1 x + p2 x^2)^M
p[p1_, p2_, S_, M_] := Sum[Coefficient[g[x, p1, p2, M], x, n], {n, S, 2 M}] // Interpreter["Percent"][N[#]*100] &
```

After we can call the function defined above, by example

```
p[1/6,1/6,5,10]
```

gives the result $\approx 55\%$. This means that the probability of victory, for $N=5$, when you throw ten dice ($M=10$), when a six give two points ($p_2=1/6$) and a five give one point ($p_1=1/6$), is approximately of $55\%$.

Obviously when we set $N=0$ we get a $100\%$ probability of victory!

---

The above will not be too hard to adapt to other programming languages, by example other major CAS as Sage, R, etc...

---

The charts in [this image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/izk0k85gb2fyv0b/dice.jpg?dl=0) give some idea about how the game works. In the chart the term "double" in each title means when the $6$ give two points instead of just one. I added too the mechanic that there is a side of the dice that subtract one success and I named it as "cancellation".

For each chart the y-axis represent the probability (in %) to win when you need the number of success labeled in the x-axis.

P.S.: if you need the notebook is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l05yeyqhnpy10kp/dice.nb?dl=0).

Comment: Thank you @Masacroso. I had some help deciphering the notations, but I finally managed to implement this in my game. Your solution is actually perfect, as I can replace my initial formula and adapt it to any kind of effect. I can even add an effect "If you roll '1' subtract one success".

Comment: @Revolter to add this effect we must change the generating function to $$g(x):=(p_{-1}x^{-1}+p_1x+p_2 x^2+q)^M$$ where $p_{-1}+p_1+p_2+q=1$. In our case, because the new effect is caused by one side of the dice then $p_{-1}=1/6$.

Comment: I fixed a little mistake in my previous chart and notebook.

Comment:  Thanks, you were really helpful and patient with me. Wish I could give you an upvote, but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Doing the case in which you get 2 pts for a six and 1 pt for a five ...

The probability that you roll $a$ fives and $b$ sixes when you throw $M$ dice is given by ...

$$ P(a,b) = \binom Ma \binom {M-a}b \left(\frac 16\right)^a \left(\frac 16\right)^b\left(\frac 46\right)^{M-a-b} $$

$$  =\left(\frac 23\right)^M \binom Ma \binom {M-a}b \left(\frac 14\right)^{a+b} $$

Assuming $N \le M$ you can win with any number of sixes ($b\in [0,M]$) but must have at least $a=a_{min}\equiv \max(0,N-2b)$  fives, and at most $M-b$ fives.

So

$$ P_{win} =  \sum_{b=0}^M 
\sum _{a=a_{min}}^{M-b}P(a,b)  $$

*****  EDIT    ******

Let $x_k$ represent the probability of scoring $k$ points, so $x_0+x_1+x_2=1$.

Then $$P(a,b)= \binom Ma \binom {M-a}b \left(x_1\right)^a  \left(x_2\right)^b\left(x_0\right)^{M-a-b} $$

where $a$ is the number of 1-pointers and $b$ the number of 2-pointers.

Taking into account the possibility that $N>M$ ,

in which case we must have at least $(N-M)$ 2-pointers.

so define

$$ b_{min} \equiv max(0,N-M)$$

The final formula would be...
$$ P_{win} =  \sum_{b=b_{min}}^M 
\sum _{a=a_{min}}^{M-b} \binom Ma \binom {M-a}b \left(x_1\right)^a  \left(x_2\right)^b\left(x_0\right)^{M-a-b}  $$

Comment: Thank you @WW1, although I need to account for situations where N > M. Also, I will need a formula for all cases, Cursed and Blessed.

Comment: @Revolter - to deal with $N>M$ just replace the lower limit on the number of sixes from $b=0$ to $b=b_{min}=\max(0, N-M)$. looks to me like your ideas about Blessed and Cursed are pretty solid. I'm not clear on what you are asking in your most recent edit, do you want 3 probabilities based on the game variant ? or do you want a single answer by somehow averaging over  Normal, Blessed , and Cursed ?

Comment: in my latest Edit I would like to have a universal formula (if such one is possible) which takes variables $a$, $b$, $c$ as input, where $a$ is probability of getting value '0', $b$ is probability of getting value '1' and $c$ is probability of getting value '2' and returns the probability of sum being equal to or bigger than $N$. (Sorry for my programmer slang) I will need to convert the formula into code later.